# Ajax gives back [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, ajax, object

I'm creating small application using ajax. So far everything goes fine, but I can't figure out why ajax gives me back staff=[object HTMLInputElement] from php. I would appreciate any help. Here is my code:

```
<body onload="init()">
    <div class="container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>pon</td>
                    <td>wt</td>
                    <td>śr</td>
                    <td>czw</td>
                    <td>pt</td>
                    <td>sob</td>
                    <td>nd</td>
                    <td>tydz.</td>
                    <td>miesiąc</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">
            </tbody>
        </table>        
            <input name="staff" id="staff" type="text"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Dodaj pracownika" onclick="add_staff();"/>
    </div>
</body>
JS:
//Funkcja init() inicjuje skrypt w momencie załadowania się body
function init() {


}
//Funkcja tworzy nowy obiekt ajax
var ajax = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
            var ajax;

            if(window.ActiveXObject) {
                try {
                    ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch(e) {
                    ajax = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                try {
                    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } catch(e) {
                    ajax = false;
                }
            }
            if (!ajax) 
                alert("Nie uadło się utworzyc obiektu");
            else 
            return ajax;
    } 
//Dodawanie nowego pracownika do tabeli
function add_staff() {
    //Referencje do wartości pola "dodaj pracownika"
    var staff = document.getElementById("staff").value;
    alert(staff);
    var tb_td = document.getElementById("tbody");
    var record = "<tr><td>" + staff +"</td><td><input type='time'><input type='time'></td><td><input type='time'><input type='time'></td><td><input type='time'><input type='time'></td><td><input type='time'><input type='time'></td><td><input type='time'><input type='time'></td><td><input type='time'><input type='time'></td><td><input type='time'><input type='time'></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
    save_staff();
}
//Funkcja liczy godziny w każdy wierszu tabeli
function kalkulacja() {
    var kolumna = document.getElementsByTagName("td").item(23).innerHTML;
    alert(kolumna);
}
//Funkcja zapisuje w bazie danych pracownika via ajax
function save_staff() {
    if(ajax) {
        var dane = "staff=" + staff;
        ajax.open("POST", "kalendarz_dane.php", true);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = handle;
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        ajax.send(dane);
    }

}
//Funkcja obsługuje odpowiedź serwera z funkcji save_staff
function handle() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4) {
            if(ajax.status == 200) {
                try {
                    document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                }catch(e) {
                    alert(e.toString());
                }
            } else {
                alert(ajax.statusText);
            }
        }
    }
PHP:
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $dane = $_POST["staff"];
    echo $dane;

?>
```

Comment: Objects don't look nice when cast to strings, that's why you should be using `console.log()` rather than `alert()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have declared the staff in a different function kalkulacja() and you are trying to use the variable in a different function ie save_staff.

```
var dane = "staff=" + staff;
```

Here as the scope of variable staff ended in the function kalkulacja, javascript searches the HTML for any element with id = "staff" which in this case is your HTMLInputObject.

So declare the variable inside save_staff function or if you want to check it out try changing the id of the input element and see if it returns undefined.